# how can get data from data base using ajax in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am tring to get data from controller which has taken the data from the database
**Blade:**

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
        <option value="{{ $category->id }}" name="category">{{ $category->category }}</option>
        @endforeach


        </select><br>
        <input type="file" name="photo" accept="image/*"><br>
        <BUTTON name='submit'>Add</BUTTON>
        </form>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="show">
            <select id="sort" onchange="myfunction()">
                <option value="0">All</option>
                <option value="1">Birthday</option>
                <option value="2">Anniversary</option>
                <option value="3">Republic</option>
                <option value="4">Independence</option>
            </select>
            @foreach($anniversary as $sary)
            <input type="hidden" name="get[]" id="get" value="{{ $sary->photo }}">
            @endforeach
```

I have tried this
**Ajax:**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  function myfunction(){
     $(document).ready(function(){
       $.ajax({
         url: "{{ route('admin.ping') }}",
         method: 'get',
         data:{{ $bencoded }},
         dataType: 'json',
         success:function(data)
         {
            $('#output').html(data); 
         }
       });
     }
     </script>
```

this is not working showing this error "SyntaxError: expected property name, got '&" and "ReferenceError: myfunction is not defined"
I am also updaloading the controller part

**Controller Part:**

```
$birthday=pingBirthday::SELECT('photo')
                ->get();
        $bencoded=json_encode($birthday);
        $anniversary=pingAnniversary::SELECT('photo')
                ->get();
        $aencoded=json_encode($anniversary);
        $republic=pingRepublic::SELECT('photo')
                ->get();
        $rencoded=json_encode($republic);
        $independence=pingIndependence::SELECT('photo')
                ->get();
        $iencoded=json_encode($independence);
        return view('work.ping',compact('categories','birthday','bencoded','anniversary','aencoded','republic','rencoded','independence','iencoded'));
```

how can i fix it up?

Comment: did you want the user to be able to pick the way the want to sort and have it updated instantly? Or did you want it sorted a certain way when the page is loaded?

Comment: i want to sort it when people select from dropdownmenu

Comment: ah ok, it might be better load all of the data in a javascript array. Then have javascript deal with the display. At that point you wouldn't really be dealing with laravel blade. If it gets really involved, may want to checkout a javascript library. just google "javascript lightweight table library". if it gets more complex than that, you may want to consider a full framework. vue.js, angular, react etc... i'm not a javascript guy, sorry.